# Merge n dimensional hashes and sum values in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, merge, hash

I'm trying to implement a logic to merge n dimensional hashes in ruby. In case they have identical key I'm looking for a sum of their values

I have a method that on each iteration returns a hash like this:

Iteration 1 `{ a: { count: 1, b: { count: 2 } } }`

Iteration 2 `{ a: { count: 3, b: { count: 5, c: { count: 7 } } } }`

Iteration 3 `{ a: { count: 3, b: { count: 2 } } }`

When I'm merging each iteration the result is
`{:a=>{:count=>3, :b=>{:count=>2}}}`

I need actually the sum of the `count` values:

`{ a: { count: 7, b: { count: 9, c: { count: 7 } } } }`

I've tried `merge` with block but it didn't worked for me.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data you're trying to merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a method that on each iteration returns a hash like this: [...]

Let's use this one for demonstration purposes:

```
def my_hashes
  return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?

  yield({ a: { count: 1, b: { count: 2 } } })
  yield({ a: { count: 3, b: { count: 5, c: { count: 7 } } } })
  yield({ a: { count: 3, b: { count: 2 } } })
end
```

> I'm trying to implement a logic to merge n dimensional hashes in ruby.

Rails already comes with [`deep_merge!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_merge-21) for this:

```
result = {}

my_hashes.each do |h|
  result.deep_merge!(h)
end

result
#=> {:a=>{:count=>3, :b=>{:count=>2, :c=>{:count=>7}}}}
```

> In case they have identical key I'm looking for a sum of their values

By default, it will *overwrite* existing values. To sum each new value with an existing value, you can pass a block to `deep_merge!`: (just like you can with Ruby's built-in [`merge!`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21))

```
result = {}

my_hashes.each do |h|
  result.deep_merge!(h) { |_, a, b| a + b }
end

result
#=> {:a=>{:count=>7, :b=>{:count=>9, :c=>{:count=>7}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Input

```
hashes = [
  { a: { count: 1, b: { count: 2 } } },
  { a: { count: 3, b: { count: 5, c: { count: 7 } } } },
  { a: { count: 3, b: { count: 2 } } }
]
```

Code

```
def merge_hashes(hashes)
  hashes.reduce do |acc, h|
    acc.merge(h) do |key, acc_val, h_val|
      if acc_val.is_a?(Hash) && h_val.is_a?(Hash)
        merge_hashes([acc_val, h_val])
      else
        acc_val + h_val
      end
    end
  end
end

result = merge_hashes(hashes)
p result
```

Output

```
{:a=>{:count=>7, :b=>{:count=>9, :c=>{:count=>7}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan is totally right and since you have Rails, you should use their answer.

If you need a Ruby-only solution, I whipped this up. Could probably be optimized.

```rb
class Hash
  def depth
    arr = values
    d = 0
    loop do
      arr = arr.flatten.select { |e| e.is_a? Hash }
      break d if arr.empty?
      d += 1
      arr = arr.map(&:values)
    end
  end

  def deep_merge_and_count!(hsh)
    keys.each do |key|
      self[key][:count] += hsh[key][:count] if key?(key) && hsh.key?(key)

      value = self[key].except(:count)
      value.deep_merge_and_count!(hsh[key]) if value.is_a?(Hash)
    end
  end
end

hsh_one =   {a: {count: 1, b: {count: 2}}}
hsh_two =   {a: {count: 3, b: {count: 5, c: {count: 7}}}}
hsh_three = {a: {count: 3, b: {count: 2}}}
goal =      {a: {count: 7, b: {count: 9, c: {count: 7}}}}

# act upon the deepest hash, which is placed last in the array
ary_of_hshs = [hsh_one, hsh_two, hsh_three].sort_by(&:depth)
deepest_hsh = ary_of_hshs.last.dup

ary_of_hshs[0..-2].each { |hsh| deepest_hsh.deep_merge_and_count!(hsh) }

deepest_hsh == goal
# => true
```